# Is there a cheat code for invincibility in SW: The Force Unleashed 2?

Tags: star-wars-the-force-unleashed-2

Some parts of Star Wars: The Force Unleashed 2 are either ridiculously difficult -- that, or I'm painfully bad. Either way, I'm more of a play-to-see-the-story guy rather than a very avid gamer and I'd rather cheat my way through than spend days learning how to do it properly.

So my question is, is there a cheat code to make my guy invincible?

Comment: Have you just tried playing on the easiest setting? The difficulty can be changed from the options menu in game as well.

Comment: I managed to proceed on medium. It's very hard at times, although I'll happily admit that I'm not a very good gamer. The reason I'd rather cheat than learning how to play is that I simply don't have time to play more than a few times every year and then I'd rather finish a game in a day than try to get good at it. The only game I actually were pretty good at was Quake 2 in multiplayer, back in the day. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: Try typing in SWFU 1 cheats: a few of them work in SWFU 2.

Comment: Do you know which ones work?  Is there a list of all the cheat codes from the first game somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking both cheatcc and cheat code guides there doesnt seem to be an invincibility code, links below.

http://www.cheatcc.com/xbox360/starwarstheforceunleashed2cheatscodes.html

http://www.cheatscodesguides.com/xbox-360-cheats/star-wars-the-force-unleashed-2/

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to as well unfortunately. However, I did manage to proceed with the help of IGN's walkthrough. I know it's silly to want to cheat your way through, but I enjoy that a lot more than actually learning how to play. Thanks anyway!